# How to find duplicate named vertex groups quickly

Tags: rigging, armature, edit-mode, vertex-groups

I am trying to merge to rigged armatures but apparently there are some vertex groups that have the same name. I unfortunately have no idea which ones have the same name. Is there a quick way to find the duplicate named vertex groups so I don't have the waste my time changing all the vertex groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you join two armatures whoose bones share some names, the last selected ("active") armature bones mantain their names while the first selected (which will be merged into the other) will have all duplicated names with an added suffix ".001".

So, you can type ".001" in the outliner filter and you will have a list of all duplicate names.

[image]